# Filtering with DropDowns and ViewData

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, filter

I've been looking around on forums and SO trying to have my Index page filtered using dropdowns.

Here is what I came up with.

First of all my controller looks like this :

```cs
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        var projects = from s in db.Project select s;
        var themeList = db.Theme.ToList();
        var projectList = db.Project.ToList();

        if (Request.Form["FilterTheme"] != null && Request.Form["FilterTheme"] != "")
        {
            int i = int.Parse(Request.Form["FilterTheme"]);
            projects = from s in db.Project
                      from c in s.Themes
                      where c.ThemeID == i
                      select s;             
        }

        if (Request.Form["Styles"] != null && Request.Form["Styles"] != "")
        {
            int i = int.Parse(Request.Form["Styles"]);
            projets = from s in db.Project
                      where s.ID == i
                      select s;
        }

        ViewData["Theme"] = new SelectList(themeList,"ThemeID", "Name");
        ViewData["Style"] = new SelectList(projectList, "ID", "Style");

        return View(projects);
    }
```

And the view looks like :

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr align="left">
            <th>
                Project name :
            </th>
            <th>
                Theme(s) :
                <br /><br />
                @Html.DropDownList("FilterTheme", (SelectList)ViewData["Theme"], "Select a theme", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
            </th>
            <th>
                Style :
                <br /><br />
                @Html.DropDownList("Styles", (SelectList)ViewData["Style"], "Select a style", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
            </th>
            <th>
                Date :
            </th>
        </tr>    
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

Finally made it !!!

Now if I wanted to removed duplicates inside my styles dropdown, how would that work??

Comment: have you checkout or looked at what's different about the Theme vs the Style dropdown. everything looks the same the only thing that I can think of is also to check to make sure that `ViewData["Style"]` has data and is not `null` that's the first thing that comes to my mind..

Comment: I checked earlier and the ViewData was returning the selected value correctly. However it would not filter the way I wanted it to. Pretty sure I'm missing something major :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's start with the obvious thing, you need to name your objects better, if you had you would have seen this obvious problem very quickly, have a look:

```
    /*if (Request.Form["Style"] != null && Request.Form["Style"] != "")
    {
        int i = int.Parse(Request.Form["Style"]);
        projets = from s in db.Project
                  from c in s.Style
                  where s.ID == i
                  select s;
    }*/
```

You are setting i = style, but you are checking it against the project id, here with renamed is what you currently have:

```
    if (Request.Form["Style"] != null && Request.Form["Style"] != "")
    {
        int styleID = int.Parse(Request.Form["Style"]);
        projects = from projects in db.Project
                  from styles in projects.Style
                  where projects.ID == styleID
                  select projects;
    }
```

I'm guessing this is what you really want:

```
    if (Request.Form["Style"] != null && Request.Form["Style"] != "")
    {
        int styleID = int.Parse(Request.Form["Style"]);
        projects = (from projects in db.Project
                  where projects.StyleID == styleID
                  select projects).Distinct();
    }
```

As requested, I added a .Distinct() in there to remove duplicates. Here are some resources:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2006/11/19/linq-farm-group-and-distinct.aspx

Comment: Hi Mike, in here you can't go for : where styles.ID == styleID since I can't take styles.ID in this situation. Weird.

Comment: I assumed Id was a column on your style table, is that not the case? Either way, it seems unlikely that you wanted project.Id == styleID.

Comment: Style isn't a table, it is a value in the Project table. What I'm trying to do is filter the list of Project by the selected Style.

Comment: oic. Let me update the last section of my answer. See if that works, if I understand you correctly, sounds like you don't even need that second join there.

Comment: I see what you're getting into however since Style isn't a table but a value of the table Project, it doesn't have an ID which is why it's weird to figure out.

Comment: Alright, by messing around with this solution I finally made it. I wanna thank you so much from the bottom of my heart !!

Comment: Now if I wanted to remove duplicates in my style dropdown how would that work?

Comment: Updated linq query in answer to use distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the same name for the DropDownList first argument and ViewData. In your case you have used `Style` twice which is wrong. You should use a separate name:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "SelectedStyle", 
    (SelectList)ViewData["Styles"], 
    "Select a style", 
    new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" }
)
```

and your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? filterTheme, int? selectedStyle)
{
    var projects = from s in db.Project select s;

    if (filterTheme != null)
    {
        projects = from s in db.Project
                   from c in s.Themes
                   where c.ThemeID == filterTheme.Value
                   select s;             
    }

    if (selectedStyle != null)
    {
        projects = from s in projects
                   from c in s.Style
                   where s.ID == selectedStyle.Value
                   select s;
    }

    ViewData["Theme"] = new SelectList(db.Theme.ToList(), "ThemeID", "Name");
    ViewData["Styles"] = new SelectList(db.Project.ToList(), "ID", "Style");

    return View(projects);
}
```

Comment: That's true, it was a typo there in my question. I've been doing exactly the same way as you mentionned, however it does not filter the way I want it to. When I select a style, it always returns me the list of all the projects.

Comment: Your filter is probably wrong. I have updated my answer with a sample controller action.

Comment: I tried using what you mentioned just now, It looks like it could be the answer but it's not quite what I'm trying to do. I used your theme filter to see if it would work, nothing happens. It always return me the list of all projects. My method already works for Theme so I'm gonna keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you really made me work it out inside my head. I made it !

Comment: Now if I wanted to remove duplicates in my style dropdown how would that work?